# Как защитить приложение от выполнения аргументов?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, консоль

У приложения есть аргументы **/on /off** как можно защитить приложение от их выполнения?
Например, зная где находится приложение можно выполнить команду и отключить его функции.

Есть ли способ создать некий файл с кучей символов, без которого приложение не работает?
И как этот файл можно изменять с помощью формы приложения?

Или, что-то вроде привязки приложения к железу или активации по ключам, с целью защитить от него самого.

Comment: попробуйте перефразировать вопрос. я не смог его понять.

Comment: есть файл console.exe с параметром /off, его могут использовать в плохих целях, например отключить все функции  приложения, вот и нужна защита от этого, т.е. вводят в командную строку `console.exe /off` и приложение отключается, нужно чтобы введя такую команду была проверка по паролю или другой способ

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Comment: Ну отлично. Чем не катит `if (args.Contains("/off")) { if (!AskAndVerifyPassword()) return; }`?

Comment: Можно носить своё приложение с собой на флешке. Тогда его никто не выполнит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> У приложения есть аргументы /on /off как можно защитить приложение от их выполнения?

Никак. Или ты разрешаешь использовать аргументы или нет.

> Есть ли способ создать некий файл с кучей символов, без которого приложение не работает?

Есть. Пишешь код внутри программы на проверку валидности какого-то файла(не обязательно текстового, можно битового) и если не совпадает или файл отсутствует -- закрываешь программу с соответствующей ошибкой/сообщением.

> И как этот файл можно изменять с помощью формы приложения?

А для чего это нужно?

> Или, что-то вроде привязки приложения к железу или активации по ключам, с целью защитить от него самого.

Самая простая привязка к железу реализуется через генерацию ключа активации из мак-адреса. Мак адрес всегда уникальный на каждом компьютере. Соответственно ты берешь первый из маков, как-то его обрабатываешь и гереришь ключ по которому можно активировать твое приложение. Это делается довольно просто: вот на экран консоли выдаст тебе сгенерированный ключ привязаный к железу:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mac = GetMacAdress();
        Console.WriteLine(GetNumbersFromMac(mac) + GetMirroredCharsFromMac(mac));
    }

    private static string GetMacAdress()
    {
        return NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().Where(nic => nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            .Select(nic => nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()).FirstOrDefault();             
    }

    private static string GetNumbersFromMac(string mac)
    {
        string tmpDigit = Regex.Replace(mac, @"[^0-9]+", String.Empty);

        string getPositionNumber = string.Empty;

        foreach (char number in tmpDigit)
        {
            getPositionNumber += number * 129 / 258;
        }
        return getPositionNumber;
    }

    private static string GetMirroredCharsFromMac(string mac)
    {
        string tmpLetter = Regex.Replace(mac, @"[^A-Z]+", String.Empty);

        string getMirrored = string.Empty;

        for (int i = tmpLetter.Length; i > 0; i--)
        {
            getMirrored += (tmpLetter[i - 1]);
        }

        return getMirrored;
    }     
}
```

Соответственно если ключ введен правильно -- нужно сделать запись в реестр или создать тот же файл регистрации на основе ключа в папке с программой...
И при следующем запуске проверять на наличие ключа в реестре/файла регистрации. Если таковые отсутствуют -- просто делаешь запрос на введение ключа активации или закрываешь программу.