# Как сделать генератор серийных номеров для программы?

Tags: c#

Нужен кейген. И проверка ключей в программе.

Можете посоветовать пример кода ?

Можно какой-нибудь простой.

Comment: оффлайн проверка?

Comment: можно и онлайн.

Comment: Если онлайн - лучше всего хранить пару Random - Random )

Comment: Я вот сдесь кидал код, который тебя интересует:
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628404/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2/628708#628708

Comment: Советую заглянуть [сюда](http://softwareprotector.codeplex.com/), чтоб не писать "лисапедов"

Comment: Bulson Для чего в нём нужны Features 1 2 3... ?

Answer (score 1):

Я вот сдесь кидал код, который тебя интересует:

[Как защитить приложение от выполнения аргументов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628404/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2/628708#628708)

но т.к. вопрос звучит совсем иначе, не нужно считать это дубликатом.
Потому просто продублирую код сюда:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mac = GetMacAdress();
        Console.WriteLine(GetNumbersFromMac(mac) + GetMirroredCharsFromMac(mac));
    }

    private static string GetMacAdress()
    {
        return NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().Where(nic => nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            .Select(nic => nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()).FirstOrDefault();             
    }

    private static string GetNumbersFromMac(string mac)
    {
        string tmpDigit = Regex.Replace(mac, @"[^0-9]+", String.Empty);

        string getPositionNumber = string.Empty;

        foreach (char number in tmpDigit)
        {
            getPositionNumber += number * 129 / 258;
        }
        return getPositionNumber;
    }

    private static string GetMirroredCharsFromMac(string mac)
    {
        string tmpLetter = Regex.Replace(mac, @"[^A-Z]+", String.Empty);

        string getMirrored = string.Empty;

        for (int i = tmpLetter.Length; i > 0; i--)
        {
            getMirrored += (tmpLetter[i - 1]);
        }

        return getMirrored;
    }     
}
```

Comment: А почему вы выбрали `MAC адрес`, а не, скажем, серийный номер `HDD` или раздела диска?  `MAC адрес` же можно изменить легко?

Comment: А серийный номер HDD так же легко можно изменить/виртуализировать. Что бы ты не выбрал -- будут окольные пути :) Просили пример без конкретных деталей, я дал пример, который был под рукой. Вполне рабочий, замечу)