# Защита программы от копирования с помощью реестра

Tags: c#, защита

В чём суть защиты программы от копирования с помощью реестра? Знаю, это самый простой и неэффективный способ защиты, но у меня такое задание. Назовём приложение, которое активируем и запускаем, MusicApp (на самом деле его нет, но введём, чтобы удобнее было объяснять).
Вот я написал программу, которая умеет:

1. считывать id процессора
2. активировать MusicApp (записывать этот самый id в реестр в зашифрованном виде)
3. запускать MusicApp (сравнивать id процессора с расшифрованным id из реестра - если равно, то выдаётся сообщение "Программа успешно запущена", а если не равно, то непонятно что выдавать)
4. удалять MusicApp (из реестра удаляется зашифрованный id процессора)

Но я написал эту программу и не понимаю самого главного, где защита от копирования?) Вроде простой вопрос, но гугл не помог.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если не равно то тупо не запускать

Comment: Вот оно ваше защита от копирования. В том что лицензионное ПО сделает запись в реестр и без нее программа не зупустится. Конечно это породит ещё проблем но ваша защита именно такая

Comment: У вас теперь две программы: инсталлятор и само приложение. Инсталлятор записывает некий ключ в реестр, устанавливает приложение и удаляет себя. Приложение при запуске проверяет реестр - если ключа нет, оно не работает. Теперь, если кто-то скопирует приложение на другой компьютер, оно не будет работать, ведь там в реестре нет ключа.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать генератор серийных номеров для программы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/635439/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Если мою программу перенести на другой компьютер, то можно просто нажать "Активировать программу" и ключ появится в реестре. Или вы имеете в виду, что сейчас у меня два в одном (инсталлятор и приложение), и если перенести на другой компьютер ТОЛЬКО приложение, то оно не будет работать? Тогда кнопки должны быть переименованы: "Запустить MusicApp", "Запустить инсталлятор", "Удалить инсталлятор"? И вообще лучше будет разделить инсталлятор и приложение.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Ещё небольшой вопрос - каким образом id процессора и расшифрованный id из реестра могут быть не равны? Я вижу только один вариант - когда пользователь залезет в реестр и будет как-то менять зашифрованный id. Но непонятно зачем ему это делать?

Comment: Пользователь проапгрейдил компьютер, поменял процессор.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, тогда ему снова нужен будет инсталлятор, так?

Comment: Ну, это уже от вас зависит, как вы сделаете возможность обновления ключа. Либо заново инсталлятор, либо в программе предусмотреть пункт в меню.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, если удалить инсталлятор, то можно ли после этого нормально пользоваться приложением? Другими словами, в моих теперь уже двух программах после "Удалить инсталлятор" можно ли "Запустить приложение"? (кнопки я переименовал (см. комментарий выше))

Comment: Почему именно ID процессора? Как шифруете? Вас точно не устроит более эффективный и возможно более простой способ защитить прогу от копирования?

Comment: @aepot, id процессора не обязательно, но я так сделал, шифр очень простой. Устроит более эффективный и простой способ - если у вас есть что-то на примете, то буду рад увидеть.